# Как парсить auto ru?

Tags: javascript, парсер

Есть учебное задание. Нужно достать достать из раздела с мотоциклами всю информацию по объявлениям что есть. Пробовал анализировать раздел network. Посмотрел все Post и Get запрос(открывал каждый), но открывается либо

```
"Request signature is invalid or out of date"
```

либо пустая страница с ошибкой. Может быть есть какие-то другие способы или я делаю что-то не то?

Comment: Вы делаете что-то не то.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko может быть вы знаете, как его парсить и что нужно делать?

Comment: Во первых, нужно определиться, какой серверный язык вы будете использовать. Потом будете запрашивать страницы и парсить их. Способ реализации зависит от языка.

Comment: Мне не принципиально на чем. Самое главное это понять принцип как это можно сделать и соответственно сделать

Comment: Принцип следующий - запрашиваете страницу и потом ее парсите. Что не понятно?

Comment: Какую страницу запрашивать и как это делать? Как парсить вроде более или менее понятно

Comment: Как запрашивать - зависит от языка. Какую? Ту, которую вам надо парсить. Я так предпологаю, что auto.ru.

Comment: Невероятно исчерпывающий ответ

Comment: Переливание из пустого в порожнее. За день от вас я узнал, что мне нужно парсить НУЖНУЮ страницу и что на разных языках это делается по-разному

Comment: Обратите внимание, я даю не ответы, а комментарии, потому что на поставленный вами вопрос невозможно дать объективный ответ, т.к. не хватает деталей, о чем я и сказал во втором коментарии. Косвенно недостаточность деталей в вопросе подтверждается отсутсвием ответов.

Comment: Тут согласен. Попробую нормально сформулировать что у меня не получается